# How do I test for a 204 response in RSpec in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I am testing the delete action of my resource controller as follows:

```
describe ResourceController do
  context "DELETE destroy" do
    before :each do
      delete :destroy, id: @resource.id
    end
    it { should respond_with(:no_content) }
  end
end
```

I expect a 204/no-content response. However, this test is failing as the response returned by the server is a 406. The response is a 204 when I hit the controller directly from my Rest test client.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of years have passed...

I would just like to note that it is possible to use the `expect` syntax and to query the status code directly.

```
describe ResourceController do
  context "DELETE destroy" do
    it "should respond with a 204"
      delete :destroy, id: @resource.id
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec) page shows how to test the response code.

```
describe ResourceController do
  context "DELETE destroy" do
    it "should respond with a 204"
      delete :destroy, id: @resource.id
      response.code.should eql(204)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the syntax is fine. I forgot to mention that I am using shoulda. I wonder if some headers need to be set when making the delete request.

Comment: Please post the contents of your controller.

Comment: Note: In Rails 4 at least, `response.code` is a string, so you should use `response.code.should eql "204"` or `response.response_code.should eql 204`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html